# How to switch git email based on host?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitlab, bitbucket

I have accounts in three different Git service providers - GitHub, GitLab and BitBucket. I want to ensure that my commits are signed via SSH in all of the mentioned providers, which is not possible since I have assigned a GitLab email at the moment, and all of my accounts use unique emails. This only verifies signed commits for GitLab successfully. How do I make it so that GitHub/BitBucket repositories will be assigned to their respective email?

Haven't found anything online that deals with this. There is a "gitdir" method, but I am not looking for this. I am expecting that Git understands what host I am using (if on GitHub, use abc@gmail.com, if on GitLab, use pqr@outlook.com and so on), and based on that, assign emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, Git config does not support conditionals directly, but includes other config files. I was able to resolve my issue by using `hasconfig:remote.*.url` condition for `includeIf`. You may remove the email variable under `[user]` block - this is your global email. Create four new blocks for the same (two for each remote - one for HTTPS one for SSH). Here's an example of how my `.gitconfig` file looks like:

**.gitconfig**

```
[user]
  name = <Your name>

[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:git@github.com:**/**"]
    path = github

[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:https://github.com/**/**"]
    path = github

[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:git@gitlab.com:**/**"]
    path = gitlab

[includeIf "hasconfig:remote.*.url:https://gitlab.com/**/**"]
    path = gitlab

[init]
  defaultBranch = main

[core]
  editor = vim 

[color]
  ui = auto

[gpg]
  format = ssh 

[commit]
  gpgsign = true
```

Now create config files for the respective remotes. I've created `.github`, and `.gitlab` in the same directory as `.gitconfig`:

**.github**

```
[user]
  email = secret-email@github.com
  signingkey = ~/.ssh/github-key.pub
```

**.gitlab**

```
[user]
  email = secret-email@gitlab.com
  signingkey = ~/.ssh/gitlab-key.pub
```

Edit 1: Initially, there were three different configs, one for GitHub, GitLab and Bitbucket, I've removed Bitbucket for simplicity.

Comment: where you put User-Configuration email and password After `Include If` statement or where? please, clarify your answer.

Comment: @Eng_Farghly I am not sure I've understood what you're asking for, but hopefully, this should answer it - my .gitconfig file is in the $HOME directory. I've created three new dot files for GitHub, GitLab and Bitbucket. I don't use password, instead I've setup SSH to do both authentication as well as signing of commits.

Comment: You should use the same email and username for Github,  Gitlab and Bitbucket because when you reset email and username for repository, committer user name and email for every commit that you make will change based on the new email and username.

Comment: @Eng_Farghly I make use of private email. They're supported in both [GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-email-preferences/setting-your-commit-email-address) and [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/#use-an-automatically-generated-private-commit-email), but are restricted to their respective platforms. I don't want to expose my email in public, and therefore I was looking for this. The problem with the other answer is that I'd have to set up email every time I clone a new repository locally.

Comment: @Akkriden I've tried your suggestion, and looks like this might be incorrect. You cannot omit `https://`.

Comment: @Ashvith Shetty Apologies; you're probably right about that. Initially, your answer didn't work for me, so When I did try my suggestion I think it did work. However, I had another underlying problem that I wasn't aware of until later on, and when I came back to use my suggestion, I think it didn't work. Ultimately what did work was pretty much in the same structure as your answer. I removed my previous suggestion

Comment: @Akkriden you're gonna have to mention the HTTPS and SSH links separately, unfortunately. Looks like there's no avoiding that. I'll be updating my answer to include that as well.

Comment: @Ashvitty Shetty I did write it here within the answers section actually (I also mentioned the side issue with BitBucket, you can copy it if you want) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76312280/automatically-switch-emails-whilst-using-ssh/76313196#76313196

Comment: NB: the `[includeIf <condition>]` setting requires Git 2.36 or newer. I also had to specify specific path for config (`path = ~/.gitlab` in my case).

Answer (score 4):

Git allows you to set the default email address for new commits in a local repository  clone via the following command:

```bash
$ git config --local user.email "myemail@whereever.org"
```

So as long as any given local repository of yours is only pushing to a given hosting service, then you should be able to assign the appropriate email to the commits.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: After searching a bit more, I was able to find "hasconfig:remote.*.url". Works fine, will include the same as answer.